# Calling Breeze setDetached() on an entity removed the getValidationErrors()

Tags: entity-framework, angularjs, breeze

Is it an expected behaviour that the array of validations on the entity is destroy when the entity is detached or if you create an entity and you don't add it to the manager (so it's in a 'detached' state), it doesn't have the validation set on  your model ? This is problematic as I am creating a form dynamically with angular and breeze based on the entity selected or created and I need those validations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. A detached entity does not validate property changes because it is not aware of those changes. The EntityManager is responsible for watching property changes and a detached entity (by definition) does not have an EntityManager.

It is also a fact that detaching an entity clears any validation errors it happens to have. I don't know why we chose that behavior (I'm sure there is a good reason). I can only report that it is so.

You can force validation of a detached entity by calling `detachedEntity.entityAspect.validateEntity();`

These behaviors are on display in the DocCode sample's *validationTests.js* - "Detaching entity clears validation errors".

And now a question for you: why are you creating and binding to a detached entity?

Comment: Thank you, for the context: the app needs to work in disconnected mode on a mobile device and I don't have ODATA just REST. I am creating a new Employee Entity 'detached' and I attach it only once the user saves it. I don't know if this is the way to go... Currently I am having issue with the tempKeys that Breeze generates. When I export to the localStorage the new entity has the "hasTempKey" but when I get it back on an import it's gone. The id is still -1 and a new creation of entity generates an error as it's trying to use -1 as-well...

Comment: Why a detached entity? I'd keep it attached whether the app is connected or not. You really don't want to do things with detached entities ... and you certainly can't assume that a detached entity to be serializable or retain its tempkey (even if the id value remains -1). I can't figure out how you could have exported a detached entity anyway. Maybe you didn't.

Comment: Exported "added" entities retain their temp keys and the serialized data know that the keys are temporary. When reimported, breeze knows that the key value is temporary. Breeze may update that key after import ... and certainly will do so if there is already an entity with that key (-1) in cache! Breeze also updates related entities in the imported set that point to the old temp key so they reference the new temp key. It's tricky for sure. I prefer Guids myself :)

Comment: If you have a collision, that probably means that Breeze has lost track of the fact that the key value is supposed to be a temporary value. That might happen if you (a) created an entity, (b) detached it, (c) reattached it (temporariness now lost), (d) exported it, and (e) imported it. Does that sound like you?

Comment: Yes on the mobile with no connection, I am exporting and importing the model to the local storage on every save action from the user.... I am now using a standard manager.createEntity('entity') no more detached. In de-connected mode I have resolved the collision with the 'added' entity by changing them manually to 'Unchanged' using entityAspect.setUnchanged(); Now how do I update the tempKeys with my local storage ids ? I would like to provide Breeze with the keyMap for the "fix-up" from within the client application... is this possible? Thank you for the feed back

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to change "Added" to "Unchanged". I'm missing something. Are you trying to capture the fact that the user wanted the new entity to be saved remotely but couldn't? If so, this is not the way to do it. As with detaching, if you flip the state of the entity to Unchanged, the "temporariness" of the ID is lost. You can't re-instate temporariness.  Most importantly, you haven't really saved it. It's not saved until the server says so. I suggest an unmapped property to mark the fact that the entity was stored locally and should be persisted remotely when you next connect.

Comment: Yes this is correct I am trying to capture the fact that the user wants to save his changes while no access to internet.I was thinking this was something that breeze could help resolve out of the box with the export import feature, but I must be missing something... I need to do CRUD on the entities and save them to the local storage. Eventually when the connections is available I need to save the changes to the remote service and do the id fixup... I have started a new stack on this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557318/exporting-importing-breeze-model-and-hastempkey-issues

Comment: Take a look at my answer to [your related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557318/exporting-importing-breeze-model-and-hastempkey-issues/19579290#19579290) ... which is the one to which you just referred I see.