# Breeze Offline Mode Issues

Tags: breeze

UPDATE: Here is a plnkr to illustrate the problem 
http://plnkr.co/edit/bwQL3o?p=preview

## Scenario in offline mode

### You create an entity and store it in the localstorage

Breeze generates a *tempKey:* **EmployeeId: -1** and populates a *tempKeys* array with the **EmployeeId: -1**. Every thing is all good and great.

### Later on, (the application was terminated the device was turned off...) you import the stored data and create a new entity.

So Breeze loads the stored data sees the *TempKeys* of **EmployeeId: -1** and generates a new **EmployeeId: -2** 
Every thing is still good and great.

### The problem

1. When you store this new data set in the localstorage the *tempKeys*
   array only contains the **EmployeeId: -2** entry.
2. Later on, when you import the stored data and try to create a new Employee you get
   an Error:

> A MergeStrategy of 'Disallowed' does not allow you to attach an entity
>   when an entity with the same key is already attached:
>   Employee:#Context--1

### The question

Why is Breeze not keeping track of the current TempKeys? Is this a Bug? How do we fix this Scenario ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was a bug and has now been fixed in the breeze.js repo on GitHub.  This fix will also go out on the next full release of Breeze.js ( probably sometime next week).  ... and thanks for finding this and providing the plunkr.

Comment: OK try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/bwQL3o?p=preview the bug is present on 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13